# Правила выделения междометия "ну"

Tags: междометие

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в предложении:

> "- Я бы сказал, нет, но у нас
> чернокожий сразу же ассоциируется с
> американцем,  - и тут же добавил,
> подняв перед собой руки, - о, только
> не обижайтесь, я не хотел намекнуть на
> расизм и, ну в общем…"

"ну" будет междометием и выделяться запятой, или все-таки это слово здесь используется для выражения усилительного оттенка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Иногда бывает трудно разграничить междометие от усилительной частицы. В этих случаях надо ориентироваться на интонацию. У вас такой случай. Но. Здесь надо еще учесть какую роль выполняет слово " в общем" . Если это вводное слово - то же,  что "короче говоря, словом; в сущности, по существу", то запятая нужна. Если это член предложения - (в знач. "в общих чертах, в целом, не вдаваясь в детали"),то следует ориентироваться на интонацию. Хотя я бы лично не стал бы ставить запятую в последнем случае.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! 
"в общем" здесь является вводным словом, поэтому ставлю запятую.